# Django raise Exception on blank CharFields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and the REST Framework to build an API that serves data to an AngularJS website. I need to make sure that all validation gets done on the back-end.

I have a model named Candidate:

```
class Candidate(CreatedModel):

    first_name = CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = CharField(max_length=100)
    email = CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    phone = CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    resume_path = CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    notes = TextField(null=True)
```

In the model, only `first_name`, `last_name`, and `email` are required. The rest of the fields can be null.

Then I run the server and make a test POST request to create a new Candidate. The problem is that even if I do not specify any field, it will simply give them all empty string values (`""`).

I heard of the `blank` attribute for Django Model Fields, but it only applies to validation in forms and not for HTTP requests.

Right now the only way it seems I can solve the issue is by overriding the `save()` function on a `BaseModel` class and check that all CharFields are filled or raise an error otherwise.

Thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using drf, you can use validators on your serializes: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#optional-fields

Comment: I think you will be 100X faster if you use Python EVE,  If you are building a REST API!

Comment: @jape Thank you! I will look into validators!

Comment: If you need help, feel free to ask. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why it happens is explained here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.null

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty
>   strings, not as NULL. If a string-based field has null=True, that
>   means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty
>   string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for
>   “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.

if you don't want empty strings to be in your database, you can simply mark the field as `required` in your form. Or use DRF [validators](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will consider changing my strategy for empty string values. I cannot use `required`, since I am not using Django forms. The DRF validators will be helpful, though.

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 2):

After some researching, I found a way to avoid the empty strings being saved on my database. I created a custom Django `Field` named `NonBlankCharField` that inherits `CharField` and overrides `empty_strings_allowed`.

```
class NonBlankCharField(CharField):
    empty_strings_allowed = False
```

Then I used this `Field` instead of `CharField`. This will raise an `IntegrityException` when not specifying a `Field` that is not supposed to be `NULL`.

If you look at the source code for Django (inside of the models/fields.py file), it shows:

```
def get_default(self):
    """
    Returns the default value for this field.
    """
    if self.has_default():
        if callable(self.default):
            return self.default()
        return self.default
    if (not self.empty_strings_allowed or (self.null and
               not connection.features.interprets_empty_strings_as_nulls)):
        return None
    return ""
```

This is how `Field` gets its default values. `empty_strings_allowed` is set to `True` by default for `CharField`, so this overrides that and makes it save the `Field` as `None`, then raise the `Exception`.

**However, other answers recommend to use DRF validators, which is probably less invasive, so I will do that on top of my solution.**

Thanks everyone for your help.